# I am using mobileVLCKit. How to set mute/unmute of VLCMediaPlayer on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have used multiple option like .isMuted property, than .volume property. I can able to mute but after that i can't able to unmute. Below is my code.

```
   if mediaPlayer.audio.volume == 0
    {
        self.mediaPlayer.audio.volume = 1
        self.mediaPlayer.audio.isMuted = false
        print(mediaPlayer.audio.isMuted)

    } else {
        self.mediaPlayer.audio.volume = 0
        self.mediaPlayer.audio.isMuted = true
        print(mediaPlayer.audio.isMuted)

    }
```

Comment: I am using mobileVLCKit 3.1.2

Comment: I have also tried with mobileVLCKit 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you found an answer to this as its 2 years old, however the only way I have found to do it is:

```
if mediaPlayer.audio.volume == 0 {
    mediaPlayer.audio.volume = 100
} else {
    mediaPlayer.audio.volume = 0
}

mediaPlayer.pause()
mediaPlayer.play()
```

Neither adjusting the volume on the fly or toggling the .isMuted property works for me. Even using the pause then play trick mute still doesn't work. But if you create the player with .isMuted=true then it turns off the volume but you can't get it back on, VLCKit is broken in all sorts of ways.